# Dropdown closing too early Html CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

I was recently coding a website with my friend when I encountered an error with my navbar drop down and it seems to be closing too early. Here is the related HTML/CSS for the site. How can I fix the dropdown?

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://equinoxhosting.net/cdn.wallpapersafari.com/14/86/kujVXw.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 84px;
}

.navigation-bar {
    
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100%;    
}

.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation-bar li  {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 35px;

}

#menu {
  float: right;
}
.navbrand {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 90px;  
}
li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: gray;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: gray}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
div.inner {
    position: relative;
 background-color: white;
padding: 250px;
    top: 150px;
}

h2 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 255px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
p3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 260px;
}

h3 {
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    top: 60px;
    cursor: default;
}
p4 {
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    top: 35px;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1DB2E3;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbrand">
  <p><font size="5">Equinox Hosting</font></p>
</div>
<div id="menuwrapper">
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div id="navigation-container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Hosting</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="minecraft-hosting.html">Minecraft Hosting</a>
            <a href="dedicated-hosting.html">Dedicated Hosting</a>
            <a href="web-hosting.html">Website Hosting</a>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Login</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Client Area</a>
        <a href="#">Xeon Panel</a>
        <a href="#">Cpanel</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="getstarted">
  <center>
    <font size="6">
      <font color="white">
        <h3>HOSTING FOR EVERYONE</h3>
      </font>
    </font>
    <font size="4">
      <font color="white">
        <p4>Want to get 10% off? Use code LAUNCH10</p4>
      </font>
    </font>
    <br>
    <button class="button">Get Started Now</button>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="inner">
  <center>
    <h2 class="title">About Us</h2>
    <b>
      <font size="4">
        <p3>We are Equinox Hosting, launched in 2017 with a passion for providing our customers with the highest quality services <br> and solutions at the lowest prices, affordable for everyone. We always try to answer support tickets & questions as<br> soon as possible, so if you do have any questions or queries regarding our services head to our contact page.</p3>
      </font>
    </b>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i can't see your issue in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by setting a `relative` position and `z-index` value on the #navigation-container:

```
#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 84px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is the update to your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/wv9yvexu/

Your problem is that your title (`HOSTING FOR EVERYONE`) has a relative position, which takes over the menu (or menu stays behind that element), so when you `hover` that title - the `menu` is not "hovered" and gets hidden again.

The above change in the css will fix this.